# preventDefault() for touchstart handler in Firefox not working - Pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, web-applications

I would like for a button to react to 'touches' on a touch screen, and 'clicks' on a non-touch screen. In case of a touch screen, I only want the touchstart handler to direct my flow and prevent the system from further handling the click event.

For this, I added two event listeners to my button. One listens for touchstart events. Once a touchstart has been detected, it uses event.preventDefault() to cancel the click event.

The code below on a touchscreen in Chrome, Opera and Android browsers achieves the desired result:
**- one alert saying "touch".**

However, in Firefox both events are detected, in spite of the preventDefault() in the touchstart handler:
**two alerts... first one says "touch", followed by a second alert saying "click".**

```
lginButton.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("touch");
}, false);

lginButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  alert("click");
}, false);
```

**Why is this happening and how can I achieve the desired results in all browsers?**

Comment: Have you tried event.stopPropagation() instead?

Comment: @Ofir yes I have. It results in no browser achieving the desired result... as expected.

Comment: You might find this interesting: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html.

Comment: Worst case, you can setup you own global variable to handle this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently unable to test. But based on your feedback it appears that Firefox is in fact not following the spec on events found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#mouse-events). I was about to find 4-5 bug logs on Mozilla that discussed this very topic, and finally found one that resolved the issue here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=977226. Definitely check to make sure you have the current version of firefox. And if you do it may be worth opening a new bug with mozilla on this. In the meantime you can set up a conditional inside of your touchstart event handler that detects the event type and handles touch and mouse events differently.. And then further adding more conditionals within you click conditional to handle browser and OS version. which is super bad practice, but would keep you going until a patch was implemented.

Comment: First of all, your solution would not work on a windows 8 machine where you have the option to either use a mouse or your fingers. It would disable mouse usage. Secondly, the default action of a touchstart event is actually a click event and can thus be prevented by the preventDefault() method. Hence the successful result in the other browsers. You can read more about this practice over at Google's developer site: https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons "Calling preventDefault on touchstart events will stop clicks and scrolling from occurring as a result of the current tap"

Comment: Yeah I totally overlooked that and didn't understand the real issue at first.